# Using data in one table to exclude results from another

Tags: sql, ms-access

Working in Access 2010.

I need to formulate a query that uses the contents of one table to exclude contents of another.  One table is a list of addresses, the other a list of profile codes, where there may be zero or more profile codes for any address.  Thus, if I'm creating a batch of addresses for mailing labels, I want to exclude all addresses that have a "no mail" profile code.

I believe that this one requires a sub-query, and I've never been able to get the hang of doing that.

General form:

```
SELECT * from AddressList
WHERE NOT IN
(select code from Profile where AddressList.ID = Profile.ID 
and Profile.code = "No Mail")
```

Comment: This is pretty close.  You probably got an error message because you need to specify the field that is not in the subquery results.  However, "not in" tends to be slow.  Look at Mureinik's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but the operator you're looking for is `EXISTS`. It evaluates as `true` if the subquery returns one or more results, and as `false` if it returns no rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   AddressList
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select code from Profile where AddressList.ID = Profile.ID and Profile.code = "No Mail")
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are trying to write seems to work best as `not in`:

```
SELECT *
from AddressList
WHERE id NOT IN (select id from Profile Profile.code = "No Mail");
```

Another way to write this is using `left join`:

```
select al.*
from AddressList al left join
     Profile p
     on p.id = al.id and
        p.code = "No Mail"
where p.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a better way to do the same thing using LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AddressList 
LEFT JOIN Profile 
ON AddressList.ID = Profile.ID 
AND Profile.code = 'No Mail'
WHERE Profile.ID IS NULL
```